# How do I fix my error when deserializing json from HttpRequest in Azure Function App?

Tags: c#, json, azure-functions

I've recently started using azure function apps.  I am passing some json data from Postman into my app when it's running so that I can test it and I'm getting an error of an unexpected character '{'.

```
{
    "testId": "001",
    "shopItems": {
       "itemName": "something"
    }
}
```

Here is what is happening.

Firstly, I have my very basic function, which can be called via it's route in postman.  I pass the above request in the body as JSON to this function which then calls a service to work with it.

```
[FunctionName("UpdateCart")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCart(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "v1/cart/update")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    await _myService.UpdateCartAsync(req.Body);

    //Return ok
    return new OkResult();
}
```

The body property of 'HttpRequest' is a 'Stream' and therefore my service and it's interface expect a stream to be passed in.

**Interface**

```
namespace MyProject.Services.Interface
{
    public interface IMyService
    {

        Task UpdateCartAsync(Stream contents);
    }
}
```

**Service**

Since we know it's a stream, I use "ReadToEndAsync" which then produces a string from the result.  I pass that string to the "JsonConvert.Deserializer" to map that to my model and that's where it fails with the unexpected character '{' which is the bracer before "itemName".

```
public async Task UpdateCartAsync(Stream content)
{
        
    var result = await new StreamReader(content).ReadToEndAsync();

    Basket cart = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cart>(result); //fails here

    var db = _connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();

    await db.StringSetAsync(cart.CartId, cart.CartContents);
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Cart
{
    public string CartId { get; set; }
    public string CartContents { get; set; }
}
```

I'm guessing here that the Steam string isn't actually accurate or that I perhaps need to serialize first, I'm not sure.  Is there another way to pass JSON from the body to a functions app?

Comment: @kanils_ I think you may be wrong there

Comment: I don't see a problem with the part of your code that reads the request body and deserializes. I do see issues such as mismatched method names and the Cart class does not match the JSON being posted. But that would not cause the error you're reporting. I expect you may be posting invalid data from postman. You should double check what is being posted.

Comment: Why are you reading Body and not Content? You can cast it directly to your object. This line is of the MS docs.
`object eventData = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();`

Comment: @klekmek 'req.Content' doesn't work as 'req' does not contain a definitions for 'Content'.  'req' is 'HttpRequest'